# AS3 delete object when clicked

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to set an object to null when it's being clicked and I'm trying to implement this code:

```
        public function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void{
        var thisPatient = evt.target;
        thisPatient = null;
    }
```

However, the element is still on the stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    var thisPatient = evt.target;
    (thisPatient as DisplayObject).parent.removeChild(thisPatient);
    //or if thisPatient is this
    parent.removeChild(this);
}
```

But it's bad practive to allow children to remove itself. More right solution is dispathing event because parent must decide remove or not remove child.

```
public function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    dispatchEvent(new Event("removeMe", true));
}

//parent's code...
child.addEventListener("removeMe", removeHandler);
```

Comment: I take this as the accepted answer as it explains the custom events as well.

Comment: The issue with children to remove themselves is the remaining reference that has possibly be created, so yes, I totally agree with it being bad practice. I wouldn't, however, go with an extra event for this, but rather make a direct call to a handler function that removes the object that calls it. Might be nit picking, but having too many events adds up and can lead to performance issues, especially in case you're developing for mobiles.

Comment: One could argue that if you care of a child removes itself, then the parent should listen for the `Event.REMOVED` event, which will get raised if a child calls `parent.removeChild(this)`

Comment: and there is a difference between `evt.target` and `evt.currentTarget`, `target` might not be what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 3):

Setting it to null doesn't suffice. You also have to remove it from its parent container using `removeElement()` or `removeChild()` depending on what kind of container you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to do `removeChild(thisPatient)` and if you put the object inside another object you have to do `parent.removeChild(thisPatient)`!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Register for a events object, you must remove all of the events. all events will be removed completely manually. removeChild on the object that will not release all of the events. the removeChild but, finely memory leak occurs. This is because you did not remove the event. Before you remove an object, you must remove the event.